# Load database base on conditional statement

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an admin page in which the admin can choose from where he/she wants to track the database data: `Local` or `Master`

If they choose, Local, then they will get the data from http:123.456.789:3306
If they choose, Inter, then they will get the data from http:987.546.321:3306

```
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['Local'] = array(
  'hostname' => '123.456.789',
  .....

$db['Inter'] = array(
  'hostname' => '987.546.321',
  .....
```

From here I successfully choose what database I want to get from the model:

```
  function get_Onedata { 
        $this->db2 = $this->load->database('inter',TRUE);
        ...
        $query = $this->db2->query($sql);
  }
```

But with the method above, I must declare in each function what database I want to load.

What I want is, when I send/pass variable such as:

```
   $database = $this->input->post('database');

   $toModel = $this->get_model->get_Onedata($database);
```

And get the database from the parent construct function:

```
public function __construct($database)
    {
        parent::__construct();

        if($database = 'inter')
            {
                $this->db = $this->load->database('inter',TRUE);
            }
        else
            {
                $this->db = $this->load->database('local',TRUE);
            }


  public function get_Onedata()
       {
             ...
             ...
             ...
             $query = $this->db->query($sql);
       }

    }
```

I hope anyone know what I am doing in the sketch above.

Can anybody help me how to do this method correctly?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this...

```
$toModel = $this->get_model->get_Onedata($database);
```

Then you would need to do something like this...

```
public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
}    
public function get_Onedata($database){
  $this->set_database($database);
                 ...
                 ...
  $query = $this->db->query($sql);
}

public function set_database($database){
  if($database = 'inter'){
    $this->db = $this->load->database('inter',TRUE);
  }
  else {
    $this->db = $this->load->database('local',TRUE);
  }
}
```

It's "a way" to do it.